# Regex: Match a string which has no initial zeroes and does not have last two zeroes

Tags: java, regex

I tried something like [1-9][0-9]+[^(00)]. But it is not working partially.

Below is an example:

- input: `000000001321054000456400`
- output:        `13210540004564`
- input: `0000000013210540004564000`
- output:        `132105400045640`
- input: `0000000013210540004564`
- output:        `13210540004564`

Could you please provide the explanation of the solution.

Comment: Get all numbers with `\b\d+\b` and then remove the zeros with `^0+`.

Comment: Try [`s=s.replaceFirst("^0*([1-9]\\d*?)(?:00)?$", "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/k7HNnp/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow, it works. Could you please explain what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replaceFirst("^0*([1-9]\\d*?)(?:00)?$", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7HNnp/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `0*` - leading `0`s
- `([1-9]\\d*?)` - Group 1 (later referenced to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): a digit from `1` to `9` and then any 0+ digits as few as possible (the lazy quantifier enables the next optional pattern to be tried at the appropriate place in the string)
- `(?:00)?` - an optional `00` substring
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: I did not completely understand the Group 1 and optional. You mentioned that it will work in a lazy manner. Does that mean that first, it will check if the optional substring (the second part) is present or not? How does the lazy quantifier decide whether to expand further or not?

Comment: I would like to understand what $1 as a replacement is doing.

Comment: @ManinderSingh The pattern will [work like that](https://regex101.com/r/k7HNnp/3/debugger): initial zeros will be matched, then a diigt other than `0` will be found and put into Group 1 memory buffer. Then, `(?:00)?$` will be tried and each time it does not match, the `\d*?` will be "expanded", each digit will be added to Group 1 memory buffer one by one. Up to the last `00` if present. `$1` is a replacement backreference that stands for Group 1 value.

Comment: That's pretty cool!. Do we always use $1 for any lazy quantifier we use? If possible could please share any tutorial or blog post that I can read to figure out more regex myself. Thanks!

Comment: @ManinderSingh Lazy quantifier is `*?`. `$1` is not related to a quantifier, it is a placeholder for a capturing group value. More about regex: http://regular-expressions.info, http://rexegg.com. A good quick tutorial: http://regexone.com.